# How to control 8V over I2C from a microcontroller

Tags: voltage, dac

I've got a microcontroller taling to a DAC `MAX520ACPE` over i2c. This DAC gives me 0V to 5V with 8bit presision. I neev to control 0Vto 8V. I think I can use a `LM317` to regulate the output voltage but I don't know how to connect the output of the `MAX520ACPE` to the `LM317`.

Output:

[image]

Power:

[image]

Comment: How much current must the 0-8V output supply, and what will the programmable voltages be used for?

Comment: The 0V-8V power will run some small Z scale trains. Each output would need no more than 400mA. I'll add a picture for what I think my power input is.

Comment: This is typically done with an H-bridge IC and pulse width modulation, not a DAC and linear (analog) power amplifier.  For tiny motors in a Z scale train you probably want a PWM frequency in the KHz range (you can always filter it, too).  Overall, it's a case where looking at what people in your field of use are already doing (include N gauge and even HO solution in your search) will likely be more productive than trying to invent something from first principles.

Comment: The LM317 requires about 3 volts "headroom" for operation - that is, the input voltage must be about 3 volts above the desired output voltage.

Comment: "Z scale trains" - that explains the 'railx' outputs!

Answer (score 1):

To get 0-8V from 0-5V you must amplify the DAC output voltage by a factor of 8/5 = 1.6. However the LM317 regulates its output voltage to 1.25V above the ADJ pin, so you will also have to bias it with -1.25V. The circuit below should do the job:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd0jXp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R3 and R4 set the non-inverting voltage gain of OA1 to (R4+R3)/R3 = 1.6. R1 and R2 provide a bias voltage of 2.083V to the inverting input. The formula for Inverting gain is -(R4/R3), so the bias voltage output is 2.083*-(60k/100k) = -1.25V. V3 provides the negative supply voltage that the op amp needs to pull its output below ground.

The LM324 has 4 op amps in it so you only need one IC to do 4 channels. The negative supply voltage is not critical (just has to be at least -2.2V) and only a few milliamps is required, so you could generate it from the +5V supply using eg. an [ICL7660](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/icl7/icl7660.pdf) or [LM555](http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/negative-voltage.html).